How to write Kotlin unit test for class derived from MediaPlayer
I have this simplified Kotlin class i'd like to write a test for:
class Player: MediaPlayer() {
    init {
        val attr = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
        setAudioAttributes(attr)
    }

    fun myFunction() { ... }
}

i started by creating a new object:
@Test
fun testPlayerInitialization() {
    val mp = Player()
    // do some testing...
}

@Test
fun test_my_function() { ... }

but the test immediately fails with following null pointer exception:
Cannot invoke "android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder.setUsage(int)" because 
the return value of "android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder.setContentType(int)" 
is null

I tried to mock the AudioAttributes, but nothing seems to work. What would be the right way to test this class?

You can see if media player itself supports testing by providing a testing api along with the real implementation otherwise i think what you are trying to test in this example is the media player functionality not a logic written by you which is not the purpose of testing since media player is provided by google it’s functionality shouldn’t be tested.

Sorry for the misunderstanding: My Player class has several more variables and methods that i left out for clarity. These methods i'd like to write test for, but the test already fails when i try to set the audio attributes. Btw. the class and it's methods work as intended when running the app.
